# Sliding mobile menu transition effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, navbar

I am currently trying to make my web page a little more responsive. Right now in mobile resolution I have my hamburger icon in top right corner and as it is clicked a menu shows up below the navbar. However it appears immediately. I would like to make the transition a little smoother so that the div (his display is toggled by javascript from none to flex) slides from the top in a nice way. I am using Tailwind framework.

HTML related code here:

```
    <!-- Mobile menu -->
<div class="hidden mobile-menu w-screen h-screen uppercase max-w-full">
  <ul class="h-4/6 py-24 flex flex-col items-center justify-evenly text-xl">
    <li class="mobile-menu-link"><a href="./index.html#omne" class="px-2 py-4">O mně</a></li>
    <li class="mobile-menu-link"><a href="./index.html#cenik" class="px-2 py-4">Ceník</a></li>
    <li class="mobile-menu-link"><a href="./index.html#faq" class="px-2 py-4">FAQ</a></li>
    <li class="mobile-menu-link"><a href="./index.html#contact" class="px-2 py-4">Kontakt</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

and here Javascript:

```
/* MOBILE MENU NAVBAR */
// find HTML elements only after DOM loaded!!!! if DOM did't load you can't find it
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
// Grab HTML Elements
const btn = document.querySelector(".mobile-menu-button");
const menu = document.querySelector(".mobile-menu");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".mobile-menu-link")

// Add Event Listeners
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menu.classList.toggle("hidden");
    });
  links.forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener("click", () => {
      menu.classList.toggle("hidden");
    });
  });
});
/* END OF MOBILE MENU NAVBAR */
```

I tried setting the transition of the main div to some values but nothing happened, I feel like the transition feature works only for some elements? I don't really understand the transition feature because sometimes it takes place for :hover sometimes for some different action. It's really confusing for me. Any help is very appreciated.

PS: You can also check the current state of the page [here](http://hustydoucko.freecluster.eu/).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `transform` with `transition` and move the element on Y axis (for enter from top). Simplified example:

```
.mobile-menu {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s linear;
}

.mobile-menu.hidden {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

Also, if you have them, remove the `display` or `visibility` changes to the `.mobile-menu` element since those can't be animated with `transition`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the idea. I updated my code and everything functions well except one thing. The space for the div that is being transitioned from top to bottom stays on the page.  I tried creating another div that include this whole transitioning menu and setting its display to none on toggle click. But in that case no transition happens and the result is same as at the beginning. What I want is so that on click the space for menu is created and then the menu slides. I tried using transition-delay but the transition doesn't happen at all when there is this display: none toggling div.

Comment: You should use `fixed` or `absolute` positioning on the mobile menu div so it's overlaying the content.